# Form request is not working in FF (Firefox) but working in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, firefox

i am using jquery to get rails Html code in my page..so i am using this code:-

```
$("#but").html( ''+
    '<div class = "newb">'+
        '<table>'+
            '<tr>'+

                '<%= link_to "Add a Patient", "/outpatient_detail",:class=>"btn btn-primary",:style=>"color:white" %>'+
                '<%= form_tag("/PatientManagement/delete", method: "post",:id=>"testform") do %>'+
                '<%= text_field_tag "patientIdsDel",nil,:type=>"hidden" %>'+
                '<%= text_field_tag "hospitalId",current_user.hospital.id,:type=>"hidden"%>'+
                '<%= text_field_tag "processType","outpatient",:type=>"hidden"%>'+
                '<%= text_field_tag "finalJson","",:type=>"hidden"%>'+
                '<%= text_field_tag "imppath",@pathimp[0],:type=>"hidden"%>'+
                '<%= text_field_tag "exportP",@pathimp[7],:type=>"hidden"%>'+
                '<%= submit_tag "Delete Selected",:id=>"2",:onclick => "return del()",:class=>"btn btn-primary"%>'+
                '<%end%>'+

            '</tr>'+
        '</table>'+
    '</div>'
     );
```

this code is working perfectly in google chrome ,safari but not working in FF, IE , Opera.
so how can i resolve it?
its generated html is:-
[image]

my del() is

```
function del(){
        //alert("in del")
    var arl=document.getElementById("patientIdsDel").value=keys(arr);
  //alert(arl)
    var tempA = keys(arr)


    for(var i=0;i<tempA.length;i++){
        tempA[i]+'"'+":"+arr[tempA[i]]
    }


    var hid=document.getElementById("hospitalId").value;
    var ptype=document.getElementById("processType").value;
    //alert(ptype+hid)


     var jsonObj = {

             "hospitalId": hid,
             "processType":ptype
         };

    var patientIDs = {};

    for(var i=0;i<tempA.length;i++){

        patientIDs[tempA[i]] = arr[tempA[i]];

    }     


        jsonObj["patientIDs"]=patientIDs;
         var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);

         // alert(jsonString)

         var ee= document.getElementById("patientIdsDel").value=jsonString;
    if(arl==0)
    {
        alert("No Records Selected")
        return false
    }else
    {


        return true
    }

  }
```

here is my arr description how i am updating it

```
if(selected==true){
  if(arr[model.attributes.PatientId]==undefined)
  {

    arr[model.attributes.PatientId] =  "'"+model.attributes.MeasureCategory+"'";

  }  else
  {
    arr[model.attributes.PatientId]=arr[model.attributes.PatientId]+",'"+model.attributes.MeasureCategory+"'";

  } 




    // arr[model.attributes.PatientId] =  "'"+model.attributes.MeasureCategory+"'";



  }
  else if(selected==false){
    var str=arr[model.attributes.PatientId];
    var n =arr[model.attributes.PatientId].split(",");
    var len=n.length;
    if(len==1)
    {
        delete arr[model.attributes.PatientId];
        //alert(arr[model.attributes.PatientId])
    }
    else{
        for(i=0;i<=len;i++)
    {
        if(n[i]=="'"+model.attributes.MeasureCategory+"'")
        {
            if(i==len-1)
                str=str.replace(",'"+model.attributes.MeasureCategory+"'","");
            else
                str=str.replace("'"+model.attributes.MeasureCategory+"',","");

            arr[model.attributes.PatientId]=str;
            //alert(arr[model.attributes.PatientId])

        }
    }
    // alert(n[0]+","+n[1])
    // alert(model.attributes.MeasureCategory)



    }
```

Comment: Can you also show the generated HTML output? I Suspect broken HTML but do not have a server handy right now to generate it :)

Comment: check `return del()` would be nice if you can paste that as well

Comment: thanks for reply i just add del() and my generated html code 
thanks

Comment: Can you clearly tell what do you mean by not working? Is it like the form doesn't get submitted or improper formatting or something which you thought is wrong. Do you have firebug installed for FF? If yes, can you check for any errors in console.

Comment: thanks for reply Vamsi Krishna ..i am trying to append that form by jquery so this is working fine in chrome..in FF onclick event is worked fine but post request is not working and there is no errors in console of fire bug 
thanks anuj

Comment: Can you post what FireBug reports as being sent to the server? You can see this by expanding the console, clicking the request that was just made, and then opening the tab marked 'post'.

Comment: this is the main problem request is not able to send on server..when i am clicking on button it is doing nothing no error on console

Answer (score 0):

My feeling is you have some 'syntax' error in your del function.

Can you paste all your code, what is keys(arr) ?

Also please note each line must end with ; in javascript. Depending on browser you are, it can be not interpreted or generating an error.

```
var arr = new Array();
function del(){
var arl=document.getElementById("patientIdsDel").value=keys(arr);
var tempA = keys(arr);

for(var i=0;i<tempA.length;i++){
    tempA[i]+'"'+":"+arr[tempA[i]];
}

var hid=document.getElementById("hospitalId").value;
var ptype=document.getElementById("processType").value;

 var jsonObj = {

         "hospitalId": hid,
         "processType":ptype
     };

var patientIDs = {};

for(var i=0;i<tempA.length;i++){
    patientIDs[tempA[i]] = arr[tempA[i]];
}     


    jsonObj["patientIDs"]=patientIDs;
     var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);

     var ee= document.getElementById("patientIdsDel").value=jsonString;
if(arl==0)
{
    alert("No Records Selected");
    return false;
}else
{
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: function keys(obj)
{
    var keys = [];

    for(var key in obj)
    {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
        {
            keys.push(key);
        }
    }

    return keys;
}
i just debug my del method line by line it is working fine and gives right values thanks for suggestion on semicolon i also added them...but still not working..on FF working on Chrome

Comment: thanks, I know what is keys but then what is 'arr', need this also to help

Comment: I think your problem is just some initialisation problem.
So maybe some browser are recognize it, but not others ones.

Just edit your code to match this:
var arr = new Array();
var tempA = new Array();

Comment: I edited my answer to show you an example. I initialized arr outside del function.